# Goland doesn't accept stdin while debugging

Tags: macos, debugging, go, stdin, goland

When debugging with Goland on macos, my program waits for input from stdin.

I can type in the console and press enter, but the input is not passed to my program.

It is just like typing in a text editor. I can type, press enter, delete everything I just did. My program gets none of this passed to it.

I also get this behavior when debugging with dlv from the console, however, I have found discussion on how to address it in that circumstance:

https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1274#issuecomment-406969034

I see a similar fix for vscode as well:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/219#issuecomment-192164367

But I could not find a solution for goland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, see the official [issue tracker report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4264) for this.

The workaround for it is to compile the application with the correct debugging flags, `-gcflags="all=-N -l" for Go 1.10 or newer and` -gcflags="-N -l" for Go 1.9 or older), launch the application in an OS terminal and then use the `Attach to process...` feature. You can also see the linked issue to see other possible workarounds.

Comment: Where can you add those flags within goland? Since I didn't see where to do that, I am just using the terminal to compile for the time being.

Comment: The flags are added automatically when you compile a process for debugging purposes. However, if you use a `Run Configuration` only to compile the project but not run it, by disabling the ` Run after build ` part, then you can add the flags to the ` Go tool arguments ` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround by adding a STDIN env variable to your `main` routine before reading input via `fmt.Scanf()`

```
    if stdin := os.Getenv("STDIN"); len(stdin) != 0 {
        stdinFile, err := os.Open(stdin)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        os.Stdin = stdinFile

    }
```